# Failed to add user to database, mismatch error? '{"errorInfo":["HY093",0]}'

Tags: php, pdo

I cant figure out why this is still giving me a PDO error. I am relatively new to php so any help would be nice.

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (userID, email, password, fName, lName, dob,
 online, verified, lastLogedIn, gender) VALUES (:id ,:email, :pass, :fn, :ln,
 dob, :online, :verified, :lli, :gender )";

$queryParams = array(
    ':id' => 0,
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':pass' => $_POST['password'],
    ':fn' => $_POST['firstName'],
    ':ln' => $_POST[':lastName'],
    ':dob' => $_POST[':dob'],
    ':online' => $online,
    ':verified' => $verified,
    ':lli' => $lli,
    ':gender' => $gender
);

try{

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($queryParams);
    var_dump($result->errorCode());

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. failed to add user to database";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    die(json_encode($ex));
}
```

My code keeps popping out this error, I know it means there's a mismatch in the query and the database but i cant figure out where.

Comment: Are you sure about this variables `$_POST[':lastName'],` & `$_POST[':dob']` having **:**

Comment: You missing a `:` in front of `dob` in the query.

Answer (score 3):

you have omit `:` in dob, change to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (userID, email, password, fName, lName, dob, online, verified, lastLogedIn, gender) VALUES (:id ,:email, :pass, :fn, :ln, :dob, :online, :verified, :lli, :gender )";
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the colon for the `dob` parameter.

```
(:id ,:email, :pass, :fn, :ln, :dob, :online, :verified, :lli, :gender
                               ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing `:` before `dob`

```
"INSERT INTO users (userID, email, password, fName, lName, dob, 
online, verified, lastLogedIn, gender) VALUES (:id ,:email, :pass, 
:fn, :ln, :dob, :online, :verified, :lli, :gender )";
          ^^

$queryParams = array(
    ':id' => 0,
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':pass' => $_POST['password'],
    ':fn' => $_POST['firstName'],
    ':ln' => $_POST[':lastName'],//might be typo 
    ':dob' => $_POST[':dob'],// might be typo
    ':online' => $online,
    ':verified' => $verified,
    ':lli' => $lli,
    ':gender' => $gender
);
```

Your variable might need to be as

`$_POST[':lastName']` ===> `$_POST['lastName']`

`$_POST[':dob']` ===> `$_POST['dob']`

Removed those extra colons

Comment: Thanks guys :D ya da boss

Comment: (_FYI: You can accept one of this answer which really helps you_)